# Unicode flat file import to SQL

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to bulk import data into ms-sql 2016, but, because of 2-bytes length characters (like Ü, Ä, etc), I am facing problem:

wrapping fields

[image: wrapping fields]

Source is fixed-length, unicode (utf-8) text file with special (wide) characters:

this a sample part of file:

```
ABS525                0128211024200
ABS526                0128211024200
ABS527                0128211024200
ABS528                0128211024200
ABS529                0128211024200
Ölrücklaufleitung     0128211037390
Ölzu- und Ölrücklaufle0128211037390
Ölzulaufleitung       0128211037390
```

field lengths are: 22 - 4 - 3 - 5 - 1

I tried every way:
- import wizard in Management Studio,
- SSDT import,
- bulk import,
- openrowset,
- bcp command line
nothing worked, actually, they work unless there is a special character in the row.

This is my bulk insert code:

```
BULK INSERT [tecdoc2].[dbo].[211]
   FROM     'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\D_TAF24\211yeni.0128' 
   WITH (MAXERRORS=50, CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar', FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BCP_Formats\a211.xml')
```

This is my format file (here, I tried a lot of combinations):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="22"    />
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="5"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"     COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ArtNr"     xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="22" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="DLNr"      xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="SA"        xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="GenArtNr"  xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Losch-Flag" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" />
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

all fields in sql are nvarchar (with the specified lengths, actually I made a lot of trials here: double the specified lengths, or 'max', etc)

would you have any advice? I would appreciate.

With Kind Regards,
Murat

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3119/import-utf8-unicode-special-characters-with-sql-server-integration-services/) which sets the codepage to 65001 and *then* verifies that the text columns are imported as DT_WSTR.

Comment: Hi  Panagiotis, many thx for your advice. Actually, before posting my question, I already saw/read the article you mentioned. It is a bit indirect way and requires to use gui. I have 100+ tables with 1000+ fields. I have all the field structure in excel. So, if it could be possible via bulk import, openrowset, etc; I would create the necessary codes and format files very rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem I am having but with OPENROWSET.  If the file is delimited it work fine.

The only way around this issue I have found is to import the whole row into a single nvarchar(Big Enough) column and parse it out with the database.  Works fine then, but a royal pain in the bottom.

If you change your format file to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="35"    />
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="RowData" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" LENGTH="35"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Then you import query can be:

```
INSERT INTO [tecdoc2].[dbo].[211]
(
    ArtNr
    ,DLNr
    ,SA
    ,GenArtNr
    ,[Losch-Flag]
)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(src.RowData, 0, 22) AS ArtNr
        ,SUBSTRING(src.RowData, 23, 4) AS DLNr
        ,SUBSTRING(src.RowData, 27, 3) AS SA
        ,SUBSTRING(src.RowData, 30, 5) AS GenArtNr
        ,SUBSTRING(src.RowData, 35, 1) AS 'Losch-Flag'

FROM    OPENROWSET  (   BULK 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\D_TAF24\211yeni.0128'
                        ,FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BCP_Formats\a211.xml'
                        ,CODEPAGE = '65001' -- Unicode
                        ,FIRSTROW = 1
                     ) AS src
```

Comment: change your xsi:type to ncharterm and for each terminator character add \0 (i.e) \r\n -> \r\0\n\0                                                                                                                    
example: <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />